# Change file indentation to 2 spaces in Xcode Version 14.2

Tags: xcode, editor, settings

After changing text editing settings in Xcode preferences when writing code Xcode indents by 2 spaces and works correctly, but when new file is created it has default indentation of 4 and I have to manually change indentation to 2 spaces with ctrl-i, is there a way to make newly created files have correct indentation of 2?

I have changed tab width and indent width to 2 spaces in "text editing"/indentation settings and also changed line wrapping in "text editing"/display settings, but new files still have indentation of 4 spaces instead of 2[preferances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvXYG.png).